# IS there an optimum scss nesting rule?

Tags: css, sass, nested, structure

Ok so I am doing an internship in a company and I came up on an issue . Some people told me that today , nesting 5 , 6, 10 times is not an issue because we have fast computers ... Others told me nesting up to 3-4 times is a max . Yet some told me it doesn't matter . As I was googling , I found again , many splitting opinions . Some say one , others something else .... What do you guys think ? I find it strange to not matter at all. There must be a correct answer to this.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 6):

There is an excellent article available on The Sass Way that explains what they call "[The Inception Rule](http://thesassway.com/beginner/the-inception-rule)" which is : **don’t go more than four levels deep**. Chris COYIER on his [Sass Style Guide](https://css-tricks.com/sass-style-guide/) suggests a maximum of 3 levels. Hugo Giraudel gives another explanation as to why you should keep your selectors short at [Sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/beware-selector-nesting-sass/).

Nesting or over-nesting is not so much about powerful or fast computers, it's about over specificity (and a bit about the compiled CSS file size). If you over-nest you end up in the "CSS Selector Nightmare".

> The so called nightmare between front-end engineers is when the styles
>   are bloated and tightly coupled to the DOM to a point where modifying
>   anything about the structure ends up breaking the front-end.

So basically, there is no golden rule that everybody strictly follows, it's more about common sense, not over-nesting and in some case specific cases.

Comment: Ah I see . Thank you for so many interesting articles . It does make sense , yes. Thanks ! I don't get it why this question of mine got so many negative votes but ok.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. I guess your question got downvoted because it's commonsense for most people experienced with SASS or something.. but it's stupid because this is always a good question ;)

Comment: also to add here nesting as in `.level1 { .level2 { .level3 { [...] .levelN{}}}}` is just the same as plain css `.level1 .level2 .level3 [...] .levelN` and it becomes very hard to ever override something on `.levelN`. you are too specific. there is less of a problem if you use `.level1 { &__level2 { &_level3 {}}}` but still there are better ways to split css/scss like BEM, OOCSS or SMACSS

Comment: @BojanKolano - It's downvoted because it's asking for an opinion, and therefore off-topic for stack overflow. You have already found opinions on both sides of the argument, and there's no reason to believe that answers here can do anything but support one opinion or the other.

Comment: @Alohci I didn't know asking for an opnion was off-topic on stack overflow, thanks for the heads up (not being sarcastic, I sincerely didn't know)

Comment: I also didn't know that here I can't ask for an opinion... But ok , now i know I guess :D Thanks for help :)

Comment: I didn't know that asking for "an optimum" was asking for opinions. Only "What do you guys think" is. Then again, @Alohci has a point: any answer here will not reveal the absolute truth, it can only repeat what has been said elsewhere.